# jQuery Chosen - update select list without losing selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use jQuery plugin "Chosen"

(http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/  and https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)

in my project.

What I'm trying to achieve is update list basing on user selection (`ajax` call (`tree based structure`))

This is no bigger problem, because i can use `.chosen().change(function())` and remove all unused select items and then .append new ones.

Then I can use `.trigger("liszt:updated")` to update list, but unfortunately all selections are deleted..

Does anyone know a way how to update chosen list without loosing selected data?

In theory I can manually remove all chosen generated

elements and then populate with new ones, but then is a problem with getting SELECT "value" data.

Answer (score 6):

This should be fairly simply if you save the items selected. For example:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a country..." style="width:350px;" multiple="true"  class="chosen-select">
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

Now, before updating the chosen, make sure you save the items selected like this:

```
var chosenSelectedItems = $(".chosen-select").val(); // this gets you the select value data
// Update the select items
$('.chosen-select').trigger('liszt:updated');
$(".chosen-select").val(chosenSelectedItems);
```

This should be able to reset the original values before the change.

Comment: very-old api: `liszt:` --> new: `chosen:`

Comment: you saved my precious night.

Comment: Keep mind that trigger("chosen:updated") must be AFTER val(chosenSelectedItems);

Answer (score 1):

The new code now updates the list without losing the selections, and it sorts the selections based on the options order.

```
$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Reference their [project page](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events).

Comment: Sorry, what about the input where the text is typed? If I have the dropdown open and I add some `option` elements to the `select` of the chosen then if `$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');` is called and the focus is on the input and there's a text typed, the current typed text is removed from the input and the dropdown with all suggestions is shown. How can I keep the typed input text and consequently show only the options that match the text within input even after a 'chosen:updated'?

Answer (score 1):

This will reload the selection after xhr request (refresh list) and delete the selection if the new item list not contains the earlier selected item:

```
var chosenSelectedItems = $(".chosen-select").val();  
$('select#GroupsStr').empty();

$.each(xhr.ReturnValue, function (index, item) {
    var newOption = $('<option value="' + index + '">' + item + '</option>');
    $('select#GroupsStr').append(newOption);
});

$("select#GroupsStr").val(chosenSelectedItems).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a few cascading or dependent dropdowns using chosen, but I have used them in addition to knockoutjs. KnockoutJS is used for binding data (in your case the select) to an object and a DOM element. Knockout also allows you to create custom bindings to handle things they may not have anticipated straight out of the box. With that being said I created a custom binding for knockout that utilized Chosen and it turned out well...

In our case we allow users to select a channel (using chosen) we then load in their locations (either by displaying or creating another select element) and trigger our custom binding which will update the data and trigger our custom binding that will tell chosen to run  `.trigger("liszt:updated")` but keep the data in the background.

Our code is rather proprietary and I don't know that it would necessarily show you easily how to achieve this, but perhaps this will give you another way of looking at it.