# How to remove choosen item once it is selected and get it back once unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Hi i problem in achieving choosen select/unselect, i'm using https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

**Question:** i want to remove item from drop-down once selected and get it back once unselected

**Here is my image showing problem:**

[image]

below is my whole choosen code:

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({}).change( function(obj, result) {
    //console.debug("changed: %o", arguments);
    
    console.log("selected: " + result.selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">
    
<div>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>

          </select>    
</div>
```

Comment: Why? Your current disabled works really well. You could make a [feature request](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/contributing.md#features)

Comment: @mplungjan that is working fine, for 500 items it is very difficult to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li.result-selected { display:none !important; }
```

Other stuff I tried did not work, but the CSS change works fine:

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({}).change(function(obj, result) {
  console.log("selected: " + result.selected);

  /* None of this works. The CSS does work
      const vals = $(".chosen-select").val();
        $('.chosen-select').find("option[value='"+result.selected+"']").remove()
        console.log(vals)
        $(".chosen-select").val(vals);      
            //  $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  */
});
```

```css
li.result-selected {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<div>
  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Here is a related question [jQuery Chosen - update select list without losing selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414285/jquery-chosen-update-select-list-without-losing-selections) which did not help